# Specifying routing order for only one recipient in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have an usecase where there are 3 signers who have to sign the same document. Signer 1 and Signer 2 should be getting the document for e-signatures simultaneously. while the 3rd user should receive it after signer 1 and signer 2 signs up. I tried using routing order property in REST API. But with that, I can mention the order for all the users and not for the last user alone. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you mean by "*I can mention the order for all the users and not for the last user alone*".  What does your request JSON look like, and what response are you receiving back from DocuSign when you submit that request?

To implement the scenario you've described (recipient_1 and recipient_2 receiving the envelope first, then recipient_3 receiving the envelope after recipient_1 and recipient_2 have completed the envelope), you'd set routing order for the first two recipients to **1** and for the third recipient to **2**. For example:

```
"recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "sally@email.com",
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            ...
        },
        {
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            ...
        },
        {
            "email": "jack@email.com",
            "name": "Jack Doe",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            ...
        }]
}
```

In this example, Sally and John will receive the Envelope first, and once they've both completed/submitted the envelope, Jack will receive it.