# DocuSign Does not Send Decline Notification to Sender But Account Admin and Recipient

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I have experienced very weird behaviour from DocuSign account.
There are Two roles for my Template:

A. **Contractor** : Signer, Routing Order 1 
B. **Employer** : CC (Receives a Copy), Routing Order 2

When Employer sends sign request to contractor, contractor declines it.

Person in CC is the actual employer, who is using my DocuSign account to send contract for signature.

Person in CC receives Signed documents, but not the declined ones.

Once it is declined, contractor and DocuSign account owner(Docusign Admin) gets declined email notification but not **employer** person in (CC).

Employer status still shows "Awaiting", while all parties must have received declined email notification

This was working previously but not today as 15th Feb 2022

I tested this via manually creation of templates and sent for sign
I have tested it on demo and production account,

NOTE: There are no changed in settings under : 
1.Recipients 
2.Sending 
3.Signing 
4.Notification

[![Please find the attached screenshot]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghkJj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue today as CC email only getting signing completed notification.

After searching in DocuSign documentation, I noticed the Routing Order feature.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594498/9417100) has a better explanation of Routing Order.

After reading about Routing Order, I just set a "1" routing order in the CC email object (The same "1" routing order was set for the signer) and it starts sending all communication notifications to the CC email including decline.

Because you have the same issue, so you just need to set the routing order against CC.

Using DocuSign C# Sdk code example:

```
EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
   EmailSubject = "Test",
   Status = "sent",
   Documents = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document>(),
   Recipients = new Recipients
   {
      Signers = new List<Signer>
      {
         signer
      }
   }
};
env.Recipients.CarbonCopies = new List<CarbonCopy>
{
    new CarbonCopy (
    Email: "test@abc.com",
    Name: "Sender",
    RecipientId: "2",
    RoutingOrder: "1")
 };
```

API JSON request example:

```
"recipients": {
  "carbonCopies": [
    {
      "email": "test@abc.com",
      "name": "Sender",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "routingOrder": "1"
    }
  ],
  "signers": [...]
}
```

Comment: Hi Adnan, Thanks for the answer but my question is what happens if I have 3 parties to sign, when you have same routing order for all three signers, won't signature request send to all parties at same time? Have you tested that scenario as well? If it works, I will implement the same, I want sequential signing but if it's declined,all parties should receive it at same time

Comment: Hi Shaym, I didn't test that scenario that is not my requirement also mentioned question was not related to 3 parties' signers that's why I post my answer and it is the correct answer because I test it. For your 3 parties signers, you are right if you set the same routing order it will send to all at the same time. In that case, you can use different Routing orders for signers then sender routing order should be that where you want to get notifications if you set 1 it will mean the sender will receive all activity notifications. That is all I understand from Routing Order theme

Answer (score -1):

> When Employer sends sign request to contractor, contractor declines
> it.
>
> Once it is declined, contractor and DocuSign account owner(person who
> owns this account) gets declined email notification but not employer.

Here is the issue, you said the "employer sends" but later you said someone else is the account owner. What you meant is someone else actually sends, not the employer, right?

In this scenario:
Person A sends an envelope to Person B and Person C is CC in routing order 2. If person B declines, Person C will receive no email. Nothing. It never reached routing order 2. Person A will get the email, because they are the sender.

The reason the employer got the emails was because he was the sender, not because of the CC. If the sender is still the employer (or whoever else it is) they will get the email. The CC in this case will never get an email.

Hope this clarifies this. You need to check who your **sender** is, it's not who you think it should be.

Comment: Person B Sends to Person A. CC is actual sender(employer) and he could be anyone and I am the owner of Docusign account(Admin), now for CC (Employer) : I have used someone's else's email address, because I am sending on behalf of Him using my docusign account and this is very normal scenario and email address in CC is the actual employer, who receives document once it is signed, that is already happening, but for declined document, only I and Signer are receiving email not the CC(Employer), why ?

Comment: "sending on behalf of", how are you doing that? Im not sure you are sending as the person you think you're sending as

Comment: it is very simple to understand : I am using API, and allowing other employers to use my platform to send emails to contractors for signature, they are paying me to use my platform for contracting purposes. So employers are using my website and I own that account , hence I am an admin of docusign account and allowing customers to use it's features. Hope it clears else leave it, it seems, it is hard to make convince docusign , this feature needs change, all parties must receive notifications whether document is sigend, or declined and I feel it is very basic requirement

Comment: This doesn't send on their behalf. You are using the API the same way. The access token you use for authentication - how did you get it? do you use JWT or Auth Code Grant?